# Access pentaho through dotnet application without passing credentials through url

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, pentaho, pentaho-cde

Currently I am passing the pentaho url into an iframe. However, the username and password is exposed when doing this. My ultimate goal is to figure out how to send a request over and open the pentaho dashboard in an iframe without the url or figure out a way to hide the credentials within a browser.

Aspx page

```
<iframe class="dashborad_content" src="<%= dashboardUrl %>"></iframe>
```

Aspx.cs page

```
public string dashboardUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dashboard"];

public async void getInfo()
    {
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "password");
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(dashboardUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/html"));
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("output-type", "PDF"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("show_discontinue", "false")
            });
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(dashboardUrl, content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you just clarify where the credentials are being shown?

Comment: @ChrisBint Yes so if you right click in Chrome and click inspect you are able to see the credentials there, which is a security issue. Also, if I run the Fiddler tool I can see the credentials there as well because the url is also shown with the credentials.